# MySQL date comparison: text string date vs CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql

I have checked a few similar titled issues, and not finding anything that explains the below for me. Please if someone has some advice:

I have the following queries:

```
# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - Resulted in: 2022-07-25 10:18:27

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

and

```
# THE NEXT QUERY GIVES NO RESULTS

SELECT * FROM `rbs` 
WHERE `rbs_status` IN(0, 4) 
AND `start_date` <= '2022-07-25 10:18:27'
AND `end_date` >= '2022-07-25 10:18:27';
```

and

```
# THE BELOW QUERY GIVES A RESULT

SELECT * FROM `rbs` 
WHERE `rbs_status` IN(0, 4) 
AND `start_date` <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
AND `end_date` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

# Resulted in:
# [rbs_id] => 92448
# [rbs_status] => 4
# [start_date] => 2022-07-25 09:12:20
# [end_date] => 2022-12-31 23:59:59
```

Obviously, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` moved on a few seconds between the queries above, but the start and end dates are well in the range that should be picked up. Why does the first query get no results and the second one does? Is it a MySQL config setting of sorts?

*EDIT:*

From comments, the following addition to the description:

1. The `start_date` and `end_date` columns are DATETIME columns.
2. `SELECT @@global.time_zone;` reports `SYSTEM` which is UTC+2
3. Thanks to @tadman, I've learned that `UTC_TIMESTAMP` returns no results when there is less than 2 hours between now and the `start_date` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns the result I am looking for, so timezone may have an effect on this, even though my system time is set to UTC+2, and MySQL time is set to SYSTEM.
4. Changing the `start_date` in the data to 2022-07-25 11:37:23 (an hour before right now), the query above with the literal string date gives no result, where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP does, and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP translates to the literal date I set in the query. Confusion galore...

Comment: Is this a `DATETIME` column? Are you using UTC?

Comment: Yes, it is a DATETIME column. `SELECT @@global.time_zone;` reports SYSTEM, and my system is on GMT+2, which is UTC+2. But when I do `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` that indicates to me that the right date is being used, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I'm with you in that this is strange, but it's also one of those things where a 2h offset would explain a lot. Try with [`UTC_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp) to be sure.

Comment: I have updated the `start_date` column to have a date that is now less than 2 hours off the offset of 2 hours, and changing the query to use `UTC_TIMESTAMP` indeed now brings no result. while `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` does. It is putting me in the right direction for further troubleshooting. Thank you! I will continue to try and find the issue, and update the question with more info as I have it.

Comment: I know it might be a hassle to change now, but keeping your database 100% UTC avoids problems like this. Time-zones are a fuss, and are really just a presentation concern at the end of the day. If you can contain that to the presentation layer your life is a lot easier. There's nothing worse than a system that's worked for years going berserk just because the server changed time-zones unexpectedly.

Comment: Thank you, @tadman. I have updated the question for further people reading this. But as per my first query, `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` gives me, now, `2022-07-25 12:37:23`. Changing the `start_date`  in the data to `2022-=07-25 11:37:23` (an hour before now), the query above with the literal string date gives no result, where `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` does, and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` translates to the literal date I set in the query. I am very confused now :-) Thanks for your help so far though.